# How to subtract a value from a sum of total in MySql LEFT JOIN Query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

```
SELECT * FROM purchases;
+------+---------+-----------+
|purid | total_q | dstatus   |
+------+---------+-----------+
|  1   |    45   | DELIVERED |
|  2   |    50   | LOADING   |
|  3   |    24   | DELIVERED |
|  4   |    15   | DELIVERED |
|  5   |    10   | DELIVERED |
+------+---------------------+

SELECT * FROM warehouse;
+------+-------+---------+
| wid  | purid | total_q |
+------+-------+---------+
|  4   |   1   |    45   |
|  5   |   4   |    15   |
|  9   |   3   |    10   |
|  12  |   3   |     5   |
+------+-------+---------+
```

I want to get "delivered" purchases with its amounts which are not already included in warehouse table. Here is the demo where I stuck: [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Ehk7woFi47wSqRHiYgWe1/0)

The query which I use is:

```
SELECT p.purid as purid, (p.total_q - IFNULL(w.total_q,0)) as ntq
FROM `purchases` as p
LEFT JOIN `warehouse` as w ON p.purid=w.purid
WHERE p.dstatus = "DELIVERED" AND (p.total_q - IFNULL(w.total_q,0)) > 0
```

My desired output:

```
+-------+------+
| purid | ntq  |
+-------+------+
|  5    |  10  |
|  3    |   9  |
+------+-------+
```

The problem is I could not subtract "total_q (24) from purchases table" from "sum total_q(10+5) from warehouse table".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use subquery aggregate `warehouse` by `purid` before `join` otherwise you might get multiple rows.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT p.purid as purid, 
      p.total_q - IFNULL(w.total_q,0) as ntq
FROM `purchases` as p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT purid,SUM(total_q) total_q
  FROM warehouse
  GROUP BY purid
) as w ON p.purid=w.purid
WHERE p.dstatus = "DELIVERED" 
AND p.total_q - IFNULL(w.total_q,0) > 0;
```

| purid | ntq |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 9 |
| 5 | 10 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Ehk7woFi47wSqRHiYgWe1/1)